# Reduce spam from Contact form without CAPTCHA?

Tags: spam, email-contact-form

I'm using the standard EE Contact Form (exp:email:contact_form) and getting spammed. Apart from enabling CAPTCHA, are there any good ways of reducing spam from it? Using EE 5.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out [Snaptcha](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/snaptcha-ee) from Put Your Lights On.  A remarkable add-on for EE - install it and it just works: no configuration or hoopla.  Have used on several installations and it is effective.  Highly recommended.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that was still around. Used it for EE2 and it worked well. Glad to see it's still around and working.

Answer (score 1):

Short of using a Captcha there's no sure fire way to stop spam. https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/snaptcha-ee is a good Captcha because it works behind the scenes, I've used it and it does stop most spam.

There's always the option of forcing visitors to do a preview first before sending, using the preview parameter https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email.html#preview - bots tend to miss this so it can stop most spam, albeit at slight inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting results: With Snaptcha (set to highest protection) + EE's built-in contact form, I still get spammed. But I never get spam via any of my FreeForm Pro forms. So I'm going to use FreeForm Pro for my contact form, as well.

I thought Spaptcha and FreeForm used similar "honeypot" methods? Maybe not.

Update: Been using FreeForm as my contact form for a few days and haven't gotten any spam. It says it's filtered out 62 now and I believe it.

Comment: Is the Snaptcha code being added to your contact form?

Comment: I installed it and it said it automatically did that, so I assumed yes.

Comment: I remember you had to add a line of code somewhere when you're using it with the EE contact form?!?!  Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Interesting. That would explain things. Reading https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/snaptcha-ee#using-snaptcha, they really hype not having to do anything other than install Snaptcha.